# Changing Factor to Numeric from Messy data

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

Given:

```
df <- data.frame(Price = c(1,2,3,4,5),
   Percent = c("5%","6%","2%","3%","4%"))
```

The Percent variable is a factor that reads: "5%", "6%" etc in the output when you str(Percent). I am unable to reproduce it with the example above. I'm trying to transform this data into numeric but cannot figure out how.

I've tried a number of variations:

```
as.numeric(as.character(Percent)) #All NAs result because of the ""
```

Then I tried to trim the "" but cannot figure out how

```
as.character(df$Percent) #Transform to character to use StringR
string_replace(df$Percent, "", ) #Does not run
```

How does one go about removing the "" from data?

Comment: `df$Percent = as.numeric(gsub("%", "", df$Percent))`

Comment: If you want the final values to be fractions of 1, then do `df$Percent = as.numeric(gsub("%", "", df$Percent))/100`.